# iPhone simulator running invisible

Tags: iphone

iPhone simulator is running on my Mac but it's not showing the simulator. Two days back I had installed the Mac OS X 10.5.6 update. Xcode is launching the aplication in simulator, and it's running, as I can see the outputs on the gdb console window. But the simulator is not shown.

Comment: Any reason for the four exclamation marks? I doubt you even need one.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try to remove `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iphonesimulator.plist`

Answer (score 7):

Had the same issue.  The simulator was running somewhere *way* off screen.  Could see it using expose, but couldn't move it.

Rather than using "Detect Displays", which didn't work for me, I changed the screen resolution and that popped it back into place.

Comment: Thanks, encountered the same issue, and changing screen resolution helped.

Answer (score 2):

Have you previously had an external monitor connected? Perhaps Mac OS X saved the simulator window off-screen the last time it was run?

In the System Preferences, select Displays and click the "Detect Displays" button while the simulator is running. That should force the simulator window to appear on-screen.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing worked except the good old IT joke, **Turn it off & on again**! (Completely restarting the whole machine worked for me).

Answer (score 0):

Downloading the latest ios resolved the problem, in my case iOS 17.2

[image]